# How can I create an editing loop in python for a whole folder of excel sheets

Tags: python, pandas, loops, data-science

I need to modify about 200 excel files all the same way (deleting the first 2 rows). Is there a way to create a for loop reading every excel file and editing it?

The editing is simply :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
file=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
file=file.iloc[2:]
```

the for loop is:

```
for filename in os.listdir('Folder'):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
```

How do I integrate this code in my loop properly that every file in the folder is edited?

Answer (score 1):

```
in_path = 'Folder'
out_path = 'output'
if not os.path.exists(out_path):
    os.mkdir(out_path)

for filename in os.listdir(in_path):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(in_path, filename))
        df = df.iloc[2:]
        df.to_excel(os.path.join(out_path, filename), index=False)
```

Comment: It works out perfectly, thank you very much!